# Conditional selection of data in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

I have two columns in my pandas DataFrame.

```
   A      B
0  1      5
1  2      3
2  3      2
3  4      0
4  5      1
```

I need the value in A where the value of B is minimum. In the above case my answer would be 4 since the minimum B value is 0.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: It's unclear what your table looks like.  Please format it in a readable way.

Comment: ryanyuyu ...how about now?

Comment: Yes, now your table in readable.

Comment: [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas.Series.idxmin) is specifically designed for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the minimum in column B, you can use `df.B.min()`. For your DataFrame this returns `0`.

To find values at particular locations in a DataFrame, you can use `loc`:

```
>>> df.loc[(df.B == df.B.min()), 'A']
3    4
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

So here, `loc` picks out all of the rows where column B is equal to its minimum value (`df.B == df.B.min()`) and selects the corresponding values in column A.

This method returns all values in A corresponding to the minimum value in B. If you only need to find one of the values, the better way is to use `idxmin` as @aus_lacy suggests.

Comment: This solution is better than mine if the minimum value in column `B` is not unique.

Comment: just to keep short notation, one may want use `df.A.loc[df.B == df.B.min()]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
b_min = df.B.idxmin()
a_val = df.A[b_min]
```

`idxmin()` returns the index of the minimum value within column `B`. You then locate the value at that same index in column `A`.

or if you want a single, albeit less readable, line you can do it like:

```
a_val = df.A[df.B.idxmin()]
```

Also, as a disclaimer this solution assumes that the minimum value in column `B` is unique. For example if you were to have a data set that looked like this:

```
A  B
1  2
2  5
3  0
4  3
5  0
```

My solution would return the first instance where `B`'s minimum value is located which in this case is in the third row and has a corresponding `A` value of `3`. If you believe that the minimum value of `B` is not unique then you should go with @ajcr's solution.