# Efficient max selection in pandas dataframe with selection condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with columns (among others) `user_id` and `start_time`.  I want to efficiently and readably find all rows associated with each user's max `start_time`.

For example, if this were my data:

```
user_id   start_time   A    B    C
1         37           a    b    c
1         45           d    e    f
1         45           g    h    i
2         58           j    k    l
2         17           m    n    o
2         58           p    q    r
3          2           s    t    u
```

then I would expect to find

```
user_id   start_time   A    B    C
1         45           d    e    f
1         45           g    h    i
2         58           j    k    l
2         58           p    q    r
3          2           s    t    u
```

I've been coming up with solutions a bit like [Conditional selection of data in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111791/conditional-selection-of-data-in-pandas-dataframe), but that finds the `user_id` with the latest `start time`, not the selection of the table for per-user max `start_time`'s.

Of course, it's easy if I iterated the DataFrame by hand, but that is inefficient.

Thanks for any pointers.

For convenience to future readers, generate the dataframe thus:

```
columns = ['user_id', 'start_time', 'A', 'B', 'C']
LoL = [
    [1, 37, 'a', 'b', 'c'],
    [1, 45, 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    [1, 45, 'g', 'h', 'i'],
    [2, 58, 'j', 'k', 'l'],
    [2, 17, 'm', 'n', 'o'],
    [2, 58, 'p', 'q', 'r'],
    [3, 2, 's', 't', 'u']]
pd.DataFrame = (LoL, columns=columns)
```

Comment: I'm curious to know how a groupby() and merge() approach would perform on your large frame vs the other answers below.  Could you try it?  g = df.groupby('user_id', as_index=False)['start_time'].max()
df.merge(g)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby the user_id column and then call `apply` and pass a lambda which filters the results where the start time is equal to the max value, we want to generate a boolean index from this. We can then call `reset_index` but due to the way the groupby was filtered we will get an error with duplicate columns so we have to drop this duplicate column:

```
In [66]:

gp = df.groupby('user_id')
gp.apply(lambda x: x[x['start_time'] == x['start_time'].max()]).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[66]:
   user_id  start_time  A  B  C
0        1          45  d  e  f
1        1          45  g  g  i
2        2          58  j  k  l
3        2          58  p  q  r
4        3           2  s  t  u
```

if we didn't call `reset_index` you get duplicated values:

```
In [67]:

gp.apply(lambda x: x[x['start_time'] == x['start_time'].max()])
Out[67]:
           user_id  start_time  A  B  C
user_id                                
1       1        1          45  d  e  f
        2        1          45  g  g  i
2       3        2          58  j  k  l
        5        2          58  p  q  r
3       6        3           2  s  t  u
```

The inner boolean condition produces a boolean mask on the multi-index, this is then needed to pass to the lambda to produce the above:

```
In [68]:

gp.apply(lambda x: x['start_time'] == x['start_time'].max())
Out[68]:
user_id   
1        0    False
         1     True
         2     True
2        3     True
         4    False
         5     True
3        6     True
Name: start_time, dtype: bool
```

Comment: On a much larger data set, this runs in 790 ms compared to 1345 ms for ajcr's and Primer's solutions.  (They all appear correct to me.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can do this:

```
df[df.start_time == df.groupby('user_id')['start_time'].transform(max)]
```

Which yields:

```
   user_id  start_time  A  B  C
1        1          45  d  e  f
2        1          45  g  h  i
3        2          58  j  k  l
5        2          58  p  q  r
6        3           2  s  t  u
```